# Magento 2 How to add missing products in Order Invoice

Tags: magento2, overrides, invoice

Here am having some orders of bundle products, after generating Invoice am getting only 3 products getting displaying, I need to add the missing products programmatically in the invoice PDF.
here is my code sample below.

```
/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice"/>
</config>
```

Overridden file

```
/Vendor/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice.php

<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice;

/**
 * Sales Order Invoice Pdf default items renderer
 */
class DefaultInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\AbstractItems
{
    /**
     * Core string
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils
     */
    protected $string;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->string = $string;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $taxData,
            $filesystem,
            $filterManager,
            $resource,
            $resourceCollection,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Draw item line
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function draw()
    {
        $page = $this->getPage();
        $lines = [];
            $lines[0][] = [
        'text' => 'my missing Products',
        'feed' => 495,
        'font' => 'bold',
        'align' => 'right',
    ];
            $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 20];

        $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
        $this->setPage($page);
    }
}
```

But its not working, its not overridden and no change in invoice. Where am doing wrong, Can I get some help?. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this code of mine: https://pastebin.com/9Fxwm491

Comment: Thank you for the response @LitExtension Magento Migration. but I found the solution. I forgot to answer